# django: populate model manytomany field on model initialization

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

I have:

```
class Config:
 enabled_options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, default=loadInitialOption, blank=True, related_name="stc_pc+", help_text="the enabled options"

 type = models.ForeignKey(Type, help_text="the type")
```

Possible `Option` values are defined in `Type`. `Config` needs to maintain a list of enabled options, and there are many `Config` instances possible with the same underlying `Type`.

So I need to initially initialize `enabled_options` to be the same list as `type.options`, and then clients will be able to enable/disable the `enabled_options`.

How can I do this? Alternative model definitions and ideas welcome.

I tried with the default callable, but I don't seem to have access to self in that callable, thus I can't copy the instances around.